# R Shiny dynamic inputs and charts

Tags: r, dynamic, shiny

I have a Shiny UI that starts with two plots and corresponding input fields for each plot. The general structure looks something like this:

```
<header>
<main>
  <plotarea1>
    <inputs1>
    <chart1>
  </plotarea1>
  <plotarea2>
    <inputs2>
    <chart2>
  </plotarea2>
</main>
```

I am able to add and remove plotareas dynamically with two buttons. This works perfectly, except that the whole main area gets re-rendered if I change the number of charts. This is not so bad from a computational point of view (it's only the rendering, not the data fetching that gets re-executed) but as the inputs are re-rendered their values are reset to defaults. This, in turn, forces the charts to change as well.

Therefore, my question is: How can I dynamically add a plotarea (list of inputs + plot), such that the existing plotareas are not affected by this?

I'd say that I have to isolate the numcharts reactive and manually trigger the rendering code once I have manually added a plotarea within the add/remove functions. This implies that I save the list of plotareas and then just append/remove elements to/from the list. However, this led to some strange errors (which I unfortunately cannot remember, though)

The server.R looks like this:

```
observe({
   lapply(1:numcharts(),function(i){
      output[[paste0("plot",i)]] <- renderPlot({
        dataset <- react[[paste0("dataset",i)]]()
        plotValues(dataset)
      })
   })    
})

observe({
    output$charts <- renderUI({
      lapply(1:numcharts(), function(i) {
        list(
          fluidRow(
            column(2,
                   selectInput(paste0("selectedInput",i),
                               label=paste("Select input",i),
                               choices=choices,
                               selected=choices[1]
                   )
            ),

            <more inputs>
          ),
          fluidRow(
            column(9,
               plotOutput(paste0("plot",i))
            )
          ) 
        )
      })
    })
})
```

numcharts is a reactive that returns the current number of plotareas to be rendered and dataset is a reactive that returns a particular dataset depending on the inputs. plotValues creates a plot from a dataset.

The ui.R file just renders output$charts.

Regards
Robert